# Strange SSL Apache "pending" hang with AJAX POST queries

Tags: jquery, ajax, apache, post, https

I have set up 2 apache servers, one for 80 port and second for 443 HTTPS. The same domain is accessible via http://www.domain.com and https://www.domain.com. HTTPS seems to work fine, if I access the web by using a browser, page loads fine.

I have script www.domain.com/ajax.php which works fine on both 80 and 443, when accessed by browser (Chrome, FF, IE, ..), but in my page I use Jquery for POST ajax queries. When I do following, nothing happens, in Developer Tools in Chrome I just see, that the request is "pending" and no output from the server whatsoever.

```
$.post('https://www.domain.com/ajax.php?action=test', {}, function() {});
```

Could there be an issue, that the page making request is on HTTP connection and the ajax request uses HTTPS ? Or is there some other reason for this strange behaviour ? Also strange is, that regular page loads fine, e.g. https://www.domain.com/ - no problem. The problem with pending requests appears only with AJAX calls.

EDIT:

I don't know if it is any important, but here is output from error_log of this Apache2-SSL server when one AJAX call was made:

```
[Thu May 19 21:05:30 2011] [info] [client 84.16.x.x] Connection to child 0 established (server www.domain.com:443)
[Thu May 19 21:05:30 2011] [info] Seeding PRNG with 144 bytes of entropy
[Thu May 19 21:05:30 2011] [info] [client 84.16.x.x] (70014)End of file found: SSL handshake interrupted by system [Hint: Stop button pressed in browser?!]
[Thu May 19 21:05:30 2011] [info] [client 84.16.x.x] Connection closed to child 0 with abortive shutdown (server www.domain.com:443)
```

Comment: Do you use session on php?
Then maybe you need to stop the locking session with session_write_close(); right after all session variables were needed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a post request from a `http` page to a `https` page will unfortunately result in (sort of) a cross-domain error. It will as you saw end with nothing. The workaround is to use JSON to fetch your data from your `http` page to your `https` page. Read [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/) article and you'll be able to fix it. Good luck man!
Other links you might need:

[Jquery API - JSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

[Cross domain requests](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/calling-cross-domain-web-services-in-ajax/) (scroll down for JSON)

Comment: Ok, I kind of suspected this, but was hoping problem was somewhere else. 
What I am trying to solve is mobile PhoneGap webapp which runs locally so it will never run in SSL mode. But I need to transfer some "secret" data over HTTPS AJAX request. 
Do you have idea how to handle this situation based on your answer ?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you with that... I'm not an expert on security. You could encode the data yourself before sending it back and decode it back in the safehouse? But I don't know if that's a good idea.. I wish I was good at security isssues...

Answer (score 1):

Same origin policy:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy